# Handle transaction on chain reorganization?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

When chain reorganization happens, do rejected TXs go back to txpool? Or do we have to re-send the transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mostly. If the transactions haven't being replaced they will be back in the pending pool.

Comment: What happens if Tx gets replaced? How can I track this since original tx hash will be deleted?

Comment: If it was replaced it will have the same nonce and sender. Only with a signature from the same private key a transaction can be replaced. If you sent a replacement transaction probably you know both transactions.